# Jquery Flip Issue

Tags: jquery, flip

I am using the jquery flip plugin and i have an issue where when i place the front and back on my two divs everything is visible on the page like so.
[image: Html page with jquery issue]

Does anyone know why this is happening i have the simplest version of the jquery code any help would be appreciated.

Flip Code:

```
$("#card").ready(function () {
  $("#card").flip({
    // axis: 'y',
    speed: '700',
    trigger: 'click'
  });
});
```

Comment: what do you expect to see?

Comment: i want to see the four charts and then flip to see the table

Comment: can you try to make a dummy fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though the plugin hasn't loaded.

Try calling your code within

```
$(document).ready(...
```